# AmEng equivalent for BrEng "circus"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, dialectal-equivalent

Is there a word in American English that comes anywhere close to what British English ***circus*** encapsulates, that is,

> *Chiefly British* An open circular place where several streets intersect. (AHDEL)
>
> *Brit.* An open place, usually circular, in a town, where several streets converge. (Collins English Dictiinary)
>
> *Brit.* an open circle or plaza where several streets converge. (Random House Kennerman Webster's English Dictionary)
>
> *British* A usually circular area at an intersection of streets. (M-W)

Both ***square*** and ***plaza*** sort of approximate what I'm looking for. Neither appear to cover the circular aspect of the area, though...

> **square**
>
> An open place or area formed at the meeting of two or more streets.
>
> **plaza**
>
> A public square in a city or town.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plaza)

Comment: We do not  have that road-pattern in the US, although traffic circles and roundabouts are becoming more popular, but I doubt we'll end up calling them circuses. We reserve that word for politics. :)

Comment: Obviously, circus refers itself to a circular property but it is widely used in situations where one needs quite some fantasy to detect a circle. Just look at Picadilly Circus, for instance. A triangle? Ok. But a circle? The first word that comes to mind for _similar_ places as the BrE _circus_ would still be _square_, as in Times Square, which seems more "circular" than Picadilly Circus.

Comment: Around here (mid east-coast US) I've only heard them called "circles". Not very imaginative, I know.

Comment: You can always use "circle".  But the thing closest to a British circus is likely a "square".  Often the "square" will be in the center of the "old town" with roads coming in on all sides and something like a courthouse in the center, along with a park.

Comment: (One wonders why you seek a US English word to describe something that basically doesn't exist in the US.  Certainly US readers will have at least a basic conception of what a "circus" is in the UK.)

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: C'est une etoile!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Owatonna,+MN/@44.08367,-93.225405,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s107611225!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2Fla_ba6yD544osTtXCg-YDJjdGS6DuJFZ0t6pGCIlsK1gvb-IKLIEzPgePdIj-8KGVeaOn5D56CbXjkvYdX13ihwsW-WTAhM%3Dw114-h86!7i4896!8i3672!4m2!3m1!1s0x87f6e64460fe90e3:0x16bca3037e40803b!6m1!1e1

Comment: @oerkelens according to Wikipedia [The circus lost its circular form in 1886 with the construction of Shaftesbury Avenue.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piccadilly_Circus)

Comment: Note that "circus" (in this sense) hardly exists in BrE as a _common_ noun. It is part of the name of certain junctions in London and Birmingham (I can't think of examples in any other cities, though there may be some). But I can't imagine saying "That's a circus", or "You come to a circus".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An American usage for "circus" is "circle." As in "traffic circle."

The American meaning of "circus" is a circular area where animals perform. The British usage encompasses this, but also refers to locations that an American would call a "circle.:

Answer (score 1):

The closest I think you'll come to a word that emphasizes the coming together of several roads at a circle is **roundabout**.  They can be very small or very large. Some highways come together at roundabouts.  Nothing goes on inside these circular areas. The area is typically off-limits to pedestrians and vehicles alike.

P.S. But there are exceptions, especially when the roundabout has been retrofitted onto a former town square. Here's one about an hour from my home.

[image]

Comment: As you say, nothing goes on inside a roundabout. That makes it a very different thing form a circus like Oxford or Picadilly... those are not just circular(??) roads, they are open spaces with lots of activity _inside_ a city.